# How to make Nicescroll only work at certain screen sizes (770px and up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I need the NiceScroll plugin to be disabled when it reaches a screen size of 992px and smaller as it messes up my menu on mobile devices by making it hard to touch the links. I am new to javascript and jQuery so your help is appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  var largeScreen = false;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      largeScreen = true;
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      largeScreen = true;
    } else {
      largeScreen = false;
    }
  });

  function doSomething() {
    if (largeScreen) {
      $("body").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#1f3677",
        cursorborder: "2px solid #E8E8E8",
        cursorwidth: "10px",
        cursorfixedheight: 200,
        railpadding: {
          top: 0,
          right: 5,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0
        },
        zIndex: 1,
        //emulatetouch: true,
        cursordragontouch: false,
        disableoutline: true,
        enablekeyboard: true,
        enableobserver: true,
      });

      $(".calendar-info").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#1f3677",
        cursorborder: "1px solid #E8E8E8",
        cursorwidth: "5px",
        cursorfixedheight: 200,
        railpadding: {
          top: 0,
          right: 2,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0
        },
        autohidemode: false,
        //emulatetouch: true,
        disableoutline: true,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You just need to call `doSomething()` after you check the window size

Comment: After the fix Rory suggested the code will call niceScroll tens of times per second during resizing. I'd rather fix the issues with the layout, or at least used a debouncer to fire window resize only once after resizing.